# Codeigniter: creating helper with associative array

Tags: codeigniter, associative-array, helper

I have a number of social networking links (about 5) in the footer of my site and I need to generate data for each of the anchor link’s TITLE and URL - and ICON (image).

It’s not really worth creating a new table for only 5 rows, so I’m thinking a helper might be a the answer - some sort of associative array.

However, I’m a bit unsure how to construct the helper’s array - and completely clueless as to how to loop the results in the view file.

Any help, or any links to useful examples, is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Show us the code and what you've tried

Answer (score 0):

In your helper:

```
function footer_link_data()
{
    return array(
       array(
           'title' => 'Facebook',
           'url' => 'http://facebook.com',
           'icon' => 'http://placehold.it/64x64'
       ),
       array(
           'title' => 'Twitter',
           'url' => 'http://twitter.com',
           'icon' => 'http://placehold.it/64x64'
       ),
       array(
           'title' => 'Pinterest',
           'url' => 'http://pinterest.com',
           'icon' => 'http://placehold.it/64x64'
       ),
    );
}
```

In your view:

```
<?php
$links = footer_link_data();
foreach($links as $link): ?>
    <a href="<?php echo $link['url'] ?>" title="<?php echo $link['title'] ?>"><?php echo $link['icon'] ?></a>
<?php
endforeach; ?>
```

Alternatively, you can just create the HTML statically. For 5 links having it generated dynamically is kind of pointless.